# Akka app-specific settings in SBT sub project

Tags: scala, configuration, sbt, akka

I have an SBT project with a sub project (which is a library) that does something with akka actors.

Just like in the [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Application_specific_settings), **I am trying to load an application specific configuration** from the sub project's `reference.conf`.
In a simple SBT project, one that does *not* contains sub projects, this works. **So why doesn't it for sub projects?**

How I load the config:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
implicit val system:ActorSystem = ActorSystem("MyLibSystem", config.getConfig("library-project-conf").withFallback(config))
```

my `reference.conf`

```
library-project-conf {
  akka {
    loglevel = DEBUG
    # some more stuff
  }
}
```

If I put the `akka` confuguraton outside the `library-project-conf` the configuration settings for akka *are* read.

I run `sbt library-project/test`.
If I [log akka's configuration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#Logging_of_Configuration) with `akka.log-config-on-start = on` I get a lot of information that I just cannot put to any good use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely related to the class loader used when you do not specify one to the ConfigFactory.load()-method.

Make sure that you use a class loader that has access to the configuration file.

Also, I think you want an application.conf and not a reference.conf, since reference.conf is for adding new defaults, not changing existing.

Comment: About the application.conf remark: You are correct (I renamed the file). For the ClassLoader having access to the config, I believe this is not an issue, since in the application.conf _is_ being read, and I can add configuration options _outside_ the library-project-conf that _do_ take effect. But maybe I'm misunderstanding your suggestion

Comment: don't use reference.conf if you are changing values in other reference.confs. reference.conf is intended to provide defaults, not override them. Use an application.conf

Comment: Like I said, I renamed reference.conf. The whole thing has nothing to do with any class loader. I think it's that a library's own (test-) application.conf does not need to contain any `library-project-conf{}` sections, and only when your library is used in another project, such a section will have an effect. I have not been able to verify this yet.

Comment: No, of course you do not need to wrap config inside the application.conf